# What happened to Java's @OverridingMethodMustCallSuper?

Tags: java, annotations, overriding

Did I dream this? I could have swore I read something about java 7 supplying an annotation that you could place on a method to ensure all subclasses call super. Has this been renamed, or dropped, or was it never actually considered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was part of [JSR 305: Annotations for Software Defect Detection](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) and called [`@OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper`](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/11/jsr-305-annotations.html#overridingmethodsmustinvokesuper).

The JSR is inactive, but a reference implementation is [available](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C2068528785) bundled with [FindBugs](http://code.google.com/p/findbugs/)

Comment: Ah bummer, I was looking forward to that little guy to remove these pointless delegate methods i've been using. Oh well thanks for the info.

Comment: @user842800 Why you would need more methods in subclasses?

Comment: According to https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/search?q=OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper FindBugs's check for `@OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper` remains as "TESTING", i.e. is not run by default.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Correct, which makes sense. (And since the question is ~4y old, and the JSR is dormant, not even sure it matters.)

Comment: Well... it does. I wish FindBugs provided such an annotation (whether it's `@OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper` or some other similar name doesn't matter to me) *and* a checker for it. Question is old, problem is old, but I found it already second time :)

Answer (score 3):

It could have been suggested for project Coin, which accepted many suggested but picked the best/simplest of the list.

You can do this instead.

```
public final void method() {
     // super code
     subClassMethod();
}

protected void subClassMethod() {
    // can be overridden.
}
```