# Strange Eclipse IDE error javax.annotation.meta.When #Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I get the following IDE error which appears inline or on the package declaration of my classes, but doesn't prevent the code running or working as expected.

I tried manually downloading the javax-annotations.jar from Glassfish and placing that in both the classpath and also on the JDK external JAR resources areas, no help.

`The type javax.annotation.meta.When cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class file`.

The error appears anywhere that I use the Findbugs @NonNull annotations; any class which uses this annotation has the above message appear in the IDE on the package declaration line. The class however appears as error-free from the Package-Explorer or Navigator view.

I would quite happily ignore this, however it breaks the Mark-All-Occurences behaviour which I quite like, if anyone has any ideas on what I might have missed I would appreciate it!

Comment: Is it in that jar? I'm not sure what jar you're referring to--isn't it part of JSR-305? http://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/

Comment: @DaveNewton Quite right, it is part of JSR-305 /facepalm, please submit as an answer and I will credit you with the solution. Is the easiest way to get the When annotation to download the JSR-305 source from the link provided? I don't see any convinient JAR download. Thanks again.

Comment: Turns out I needed annotation.jar from the Findbugs 2.0 package in my classpath so that the errors would be resolved, I had a sinking feeling whilst downloading JSR-305 that I had missed something obvious and I had! thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FindBugs jar already contains a `jsr-305.jar`, which contains an implementation of JSR-305.

More info in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8448084/438992).

*Edit* Oh, you already did that--I didn't even know it was in annotations.jar as well.